# Cleaning a dataframe in function and returning the dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, series

Hello i am new to Python and i have been trying to write a function to clean a text data which is stored in a dataframe.

```
def clean(dataset):
    dataset = dataset.apply(lambda x: " ".join(x.lower() for x in x.split()))
    dataset = dataset.str.replace('[^\w\s]','')
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
    stop = stopwords.words('english')
    dataset = dataset.apply(lambda x: " ".join(x for x in x.split() if x not in stop))
```

so when i call the above function like " clean(df['comments'] " i want the comments column with dataframe to be replaced with the cleaned text from the function. 
TIA.

Comment: How is your data stored? Using pure python or something like pandas?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

So you could define your function so that it can accept any string, independently of whether it is in a Pandas dataframe.

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

def clean(x):
    x = x.lower()
    x = re.sub('[^\w\s]', '', x)
    stop = stopwords.words('english')
    x = [word for word in x.split() if x not in stop]
    return " ".join(x)
```

Now you can apply that function to your string column.

```
test_strs = ['THIS IS A TEST!', 'another test', 'JUS!*(*UDFLJ)']
df = pd.DataFrame(test_strs, columns=['text'])
df['new_text'] = df.apply(lambda x: clean(x.text), axis=1)
```

That gives us this:

```
text             new_text
THIS IS A TEST! this is a test
another test    another test
JUS!*(*UDFLJ)   jusudflj
```

Comment: Nice, only comment is I think you should use `pd.Series.apply` and avoid `lambda`, i.e. `df['new_text'] = df['text'].apply(clean)`.

Answer (score 1):

A few pointers:

1. To make a series of strings lower case, use in-built methods such as [`pd.Series.str.lower`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lower.html) rather than [`pd.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html). `apply` + `lambda` is a thinly veiled inefficient loop.
2. Chaining operations is natural with multiple operations.
3. Feeding a series into a function and returning just a series is anti-pattern for Pandas. You should either (a) feed in a dataframe and modify your series, or (b) use `pd.Series.apply` with a function applied to each element sequentially.

Combining these points you can restructure your logic as follows for a given dataframe `df` with series `df['comments']`:

```
def cleaner(df, col_name):
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
    stop = stopwords.words('english')

    def remove_stops(x, stopwordseq):
        return ' '.join(x for x in x.split() if x not in stopwordseq)

    df[col_name] = df[col_name].str.lower()\
                               .str.replace('[^\w\s]', '')
                               .apply(remove_stops, stop)
    return df

df = df.pipe(cleaner, 'comments')
```

The 3 lines in turn convert the series to lowercase, filter for alphanumeric & whitespace only, and remove stopwords via the function `remove_stops`. [`pd.DataFrame.pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) is a convenience method to pass a dataframe through a function.